# Marca d'agua em imagem no laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, imagem, biblioteca

Olá, alguém sabe como eu poderia fazer para que toda imagem que é feito o upload no laravel tenha uma marca d'água?

A imagem é enviada por um formulário e através do `$request->file('img')` no *controller* eu adiciono na pasta e o nome da imagem no banco, mas como colocar essa marca d'água em png na imagem dentro do método no *controller*?

`mergeimage()` do php não funciona.

Obrigado

Comment: Começa por aqui [http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o pacote [intervention/image](https://packagist.org/packages/intervention/image), ele se integra facilmente ao framework Laravel seguindo o [passo a passo](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation) de instalação e depois [integração](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation#integration).

Passo a passo

```
$ php composer.phar require intervention/image
```

Depois de instalado o pacote no seu Laravel, vai no `config/app.php` e adicione em no *array* de `providers` mais essa linha:

```
Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class
```

e para facilitar digite no *array* de `$aliases`

```
'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class
```

e para finalizar a instalação e funcionamento do pacote digite na linha de comando

```
$ php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProviderLaravel5"
```

Como trabalhar com esse pacote:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    $img = Image::make('foo.jpg')->resize(300, 200);

    return $img->response('jpg');
});
```

No seu caso especifico, ao gravar a imagem em disco, carregue novamente e chame  método [insert](http://image.intervention.io/api/insert) com os parâmetro de pasta e nome do arquivo com a extensão `.png` para criar a mascara na sua imagem e mande salvar novamente.

Exemplo:

```
// open an image file
$img = Image::make('public/foo.jpg');

// now you are able to resize the instance
$img->resize(320, 240);

// and insert a watermark for example
$img->insert('public/watermark.png');

// finally we save the image as a new file
$img->save('public/bar.jpg');
```

*Fonte:* [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/)

Também pode usar diretamente quando enviar a foto:

```
Image::make($request->file('img')->getPathname());
```